# Facebook fan page id not working with open graph sql query

Tags: sql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

So I have some code that fan page albums through the graph, but it won't work with my fan page id. I have tried other fan page ids and they work. I also went to the developer site and used their open graph example, replacing the album id and page id in the location bar with mine. This still doesn't work.

It seems like my fan page id is no longer associated with my actual "fan page." I would like to find out how to correct this, if possible! Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you're doing here? It's difficult to understand your question - the phrase 'code that fan page albums' is missing a verb

Comment: Sorry about the poor grammar. In a nutshell, I am displaying a Facebook fan page's albums on their actual website (instead of hosting twice, and the gallery gets populated automatically). However, in recent weeks, the fan page id no longer returns any information within the Open Graph SQL Query. I have hard coded other fan pages, and they return information. I also tested my fan page id with this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926859/how-to-access-facebook-fan-page-photos-within-external-website[ and still returned blank data.

Comment: My Fan Page id is 353315914694387. The piece of code I am using works with other fan page ids, but no longer works with mine. So I was am assuming something happened on FB's end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found the answer. Geographic restrictions were preventing me from pulling the fan page data. Here's the link to the solution.

[Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-on-fan-page-details)